# SettingWithCopyWarning warning in python

Tags: python, pandas

I was getting `SettingWithCopyWarning` in pandas python. Here is my code.

```
def get_priority(x):
    if x['src_id'] is "":
        return 99
    elif x['priority'] is "":
        return 98
    else:
        return x['priority']

Admits_Prelim1['priority'] = Admits_Prelim1.apply(get_priority, axis=1)
```

When i was executing like this, it is throwing `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning. So, I changed like this.

```
Admits_Prelim1.loc[Admits_Prelim1['src_prov_id'] == "", 'priority'] = 99
Admits_Prelim1.loc[Admits_Prelim1['priority'] == "", 'priority'] = 98
Admits_Prelim1.loc[((Admits_Prelim1['priority'] != 98) & (Admits_Prelim1['priority'] != 99)), 'priority'] = Admits_Prelim1['priority']
```

Here is the exact message, that i am getting.

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/mapr/datalake/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:465: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

I'm still facing the issues. What am i going wrong? Can some one help me here? Thank you.

Comment: What is `Admits_Prelim1` initially? Is it a slice of some other `DF` you were using before?

Comment: `Admits_Prelim1` is DF, I'm creating this by keeping unique rows of another dataframe.

Comment: Ok, so when you're creating just add a `.copy()` at the end of the initial `DF` as a chained syntax. Right now, it's confused whether you're working on a view or a copy of the original `DF`.

Comment: okay, I'm creating df like this, `Admits_Prelim1 = all_provs.drop_duplicates(keep='first')`, should it be `Admits_Prelim1 = all_provs.drop_duplicates(keep='first').copy()` ?

Comment: Yeah, that is the way it should be.

Comment: okay let me try and check, I am dealing with huge df's, it shouldn't be a prob, right?

Comment: I did that,  But it is in running still.

Comment: I guess, it is not working!! can you give me other way!!

Comment: Can you share the entire code until the `loc` statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137823/discussion-between-subro-and-nickil-maveli).